# getJSON no return

Tags: jquery, getjson

I am trying return the result from a getJSON request.

If I go straight to the URL below the page will return this:

```
{"users":[{"id":"77","user_id":"27","target":"36","session_id":"28052014","name":"My name","pin":"1234","car":"10","bike":"10","petrol":"200"}
```

I've added "alert(result);" but no alert is happening at all.

Is the code below missing something?

```
$.getJSON("mysite.com/api/?test", function(result){

          alert(result);

      });
```

Comment: Does your console have any errors?

Comment: Do you have json `Content-Type` in the header of your json url ?

Comment: No errors in console and yes content-type is set

Comment: Your json is not valid format missing "] }" in end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need `Content-Type: application/json` in your API, in the headers that are sent with the json result
2. You need `http://` or `https://` prepend to `"mysite.com/api/?test"`
3. If the domain is not same origin, send `CORS` headers
4. Valid JSON: Your's is missing `]}` at the end
5. watch the output in the console
6. make sure jquery is loaded before you use `$.getJSON`, e.g. wrap in in a `$(document).ready()` callback.